# Php form data insertion in to database in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert some form post data in database but it shows the error:

```
Error: INSERT INTO user_data (name, age, gender,happy,sad,angry) VALUES (Sourav,23,male,3.5,2.75,1.5)
Unknown column 'Sourav' in 'field list'
```

I used the query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_data (name, age, gender,happy,sad,angry)
VALUES (" . $name . "," . $age . "," . $gender . "," . $happyness . "," . $sadness . "," . $angryness . ")";
```

Comment: Never ever pass user input directly to your database queries. At least use some kind of parameter escaping or mysqli/pdo to avoid mysql injections.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put the string values inside quotes. Update the code as below.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_data (name, age, gender,happy,sad,angry)
VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $age . "','" . $gender . "','" . $happyness . "','" . $sadness . "','" . $angryness . "')";
```

Also, your code isn't safe. Use escape string while inserting form data.

Comment: What about mysql injections?

Comment: That's why I mentioned in my answer to use escape string if inserting the form data/user input

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_data (name, age, gender,happy,sad,angry)
VALUES ('$name','$age','$gender','$happyness','$sadness','$angryness')";
```

Answer (score 0):

USE `''` like `'Sourav'`

```
INSERT INTO user_data (name, age, gender,happy,sad,angry) 
VALUES ('Sourav','23','male','3.5','2.75','1.5')
```

or like that

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_data (name, age, gender,happy,sad,angry)
VALUES ('$name','$age','$gender','$happyness','$sadness','$angryness')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_data (name, age, gender,happy,sad,angry)
VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $age . "','" . $gender . "','" . $happyness . "','" . $sadness . "','" . $angryness . "')";
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You should really have a look at the mysqli or [pdo](http://php.net/pdo) extension - or at least use some kind of quoting on your parameters like **mysql_real_escape_string**. Directly passing user input to database queries can easily be used for mysql injections.

Using pdo you could write your code like this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$name = 'BOB';
$password = 'badpass';
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(`hexvalue`, `password`) VALUES(HEX(?), PASSWORD(?))");
$stmt->execute(array($name, $password));
```